# How a script takes data from a controller in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using vs 2010 and making mvc3 project. I have some data in database. I can make a controller that takes the data from data base and send these to the view. That is ok. What I want to do is to use these datas in the script.

Ex: Controller sends an image list that includes Info,Url,Date information. I want the script show this images one by one.

Question is:

1-How a script take data from controller? (data is image list)

Comment: What do you mean by "a script".  Some javascript?  Are you trying to do some AJAX type stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) from your controller action, instead of a [ViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult.aspx).

Look at this blog post: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/aspnet-mvc-jquery-json